# Creating a connection with WildFly 10 and Jaybird 3.0 fails

Tags: java, wildfly, firebird, wildfly-10, jaybird

I have upgraded my Jaybird dependency in Wildfly 10 from Jaybird 2.2.11 to Jaybird 3.0.0-alpha-1. When I try to create a connection I now get the following exceptions.

The first connection after startup (when testing in the admin console):

```
2016-08-27 10:50:45,354 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (External Management Request Threads -- 2) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:352)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1320)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:496)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.internalTestConnection(AbstractPool.java:1052)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool.testConnection(OnePool.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$TestConnectionInPool.invokeCommandOn(PoolOperations.java:234)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$1.execute(PoolOperations.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:890)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:659)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1329)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:400)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:222)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiHandler.java:219)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.encoding.EncodingHandler.handleRequest(EncodingHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler$1.run(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler$1.run(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:68)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler.handleRequest(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler.handleRequest(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:63)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.BlockingHandler.handleRequest(BlockingHandler.java:56)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiCheckHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiCheckHandler.java:95)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.firebirdsql.encodings.EncodingSet: Provider org.firebirdsql.encodings.DefaultEncodingSet could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.firebirdsql.encodings.EncodingFactory.loadEncodingSets(EncodingFactory.java:318)
    at org.firebirdsql.encodings.EncodingFactory.createInstance(EncodingFactory.java:474)
    at org.firebirdsql.encodings.EncodingFactory.access$000(EncodingFactory.java:36)
    at org.firebirdsql.encodings.EncodingFactory$DefaultEncodingFactory.<clinit>(EncodingFactory.java:59)
    at org.firebirdsql.encodings.EncodingFactory.getPlatformDefault(EncodingFactory.java:428)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriverPropertyManager.handleEncodings(FBDriverPropertyManager.java:241)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriverPropertyManager.normalize(FBDriverPropertyManager.java:208)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver.connect(FBDriver.java:116)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException from [Module "org.firebirdsql:main" from local module loader @1c2c22f3 (finder: local module finder @18e8568 (roots: D:\DevSoft\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules,D:\DevSoft\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 47 more
```

Subsequent attempts to test the connection:

```
2016-08-27 10:50:52,349 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (External Management Request Threads -- 4) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:352)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1320)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:496)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.internalTestConnection(AbstractPool.java:1052)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool.testConnection(OnePool.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$TestConnectionInPool.invokeCommandOn(PoolOperations.java:234)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$1.execute(PoolOperations.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:890)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:659)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1329)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:400)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:222)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiHandler.java:219)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.encoding.EncodingHandler.handleRequest(EncodingHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler$1.run(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler$1.run(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:68)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler.handleRequest(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectDoAsHandler.handleRequest(SubjectDoAsHandler.java:63)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.BlockingHandler.handleRequest(BlockingHandler.java:56)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiCheckHandler.handleRequest(DomainApiCheckHandler.java:95)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.firebirdsql.encodings.EncodingFactory$DefaultEncodingFactory
    at org.firebirdsql.encodings.EncodingFactory.getPlatformDefault(EncodingFactory.java:428)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriverPropertyManager.handleEncodings(FBDriverPropertyManager.java:241)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriverPropertyManager.normalize(FBDriverPropertyManager.java:208)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver.connect(FBDriver.java:116)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
    ... 31 more
```

I use the following `module.xml` for the Jaybird driver:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.firebirdsql">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="jaybird-3.0.0-alpha-1.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.resource.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

What is causing this, and how can I solve it?

NOTE: This question/answer is derived from the bug report [JDBC-449](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-449)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of the question, test versions of Jaybird 3 also depended on classes in `javax.xml.bind` as indicated by `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException`. This exception causes the loading of the encoding definitions to fail, which then causes the loading of `org.firebirdsql.encodings.EncodingFactory$DefaultEncodingFactory` to fail. As a result, no connection can be made.

The exception on subsequent attempts is caused by the fact that `EncodingFactory$DefaultEncodingFactory` could not be loaded.

**Note**: the dependency on `javax.xml.bind` has been removed in the final Jaybird 3.0.0 release, so the workaround below is **not** necessary with the final release of Jaybird 3 and higher (see note below on Jaybird 3.0.4 and higher).

The solution is to add a dependency on `javax.xml.bind.api` to the dependencies of your Jaybird module:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.firebirdsql">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="jaybird-3.0.0-alpha-1.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.resource.api"/>
    <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/> <!-- Add this -->
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

---

### Note for Jaybird 3.0.4 and higher

Jaybird 3.0.4 for Java 7 only reintroduced a dependency on JAXB. If possible, switch to the Java 8 version of Jaybird, otherwise apply this solution.