# JBoss EAP6 - Failed to create JDBC Datasource (Microsoft SQL Server)

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, jndi, mssql-jdbc

I'm trying to create a JDBC Datasource, pointing to a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 database, on a JBoss EAP6 instance. During the tests I always end up getting the same error message:

```
Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
        ("data-source" => "MyDataSource")
    ],
    "operation" => "test-connection-in-pool"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "JBAS010440: failed to invoke operation: JBAS010447: Connection is not valid",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Following you will find the module XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="sqljdbc.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>

</module>
```

and the subsystem configuration (standalone.xml):

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/jdbc/mydatasource" pool-name="mydatasource" enabled="true" use-ccm="true" statistics-enabled="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://ip_address:1433;databaseName=db1</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
                    <driver>sqljdbc</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>username</user-name>
                        <password>password</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                    </validation>
                    <timeout>
                        <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>
                        <blocking-timeout-millis>0</blocking-timeout-millis>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
                        <query-timeout>0</query-timeout>
                        <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
                        <allocation-retry>0</allocation-retry>
                        <allocation-retry-wait-millis>0</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
                    </timeout>
                    <statement>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="sqljdbc" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc">
                        <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

The Java environment is configured to use Java7 64-bit (specifically, the 1.7.0_79 JDK). 
The driver/jar file is also aligned with the same environment (sqljdbc4).

I tried replicating a very similar configuration on Apache Tomcat 7. In this case I didn't encounter a single problem. Unfortunately, I cannot use Tomcat in production.

I think it's importat to let you know that all my tests were conducted on a Windows 10 (1803) laptop.

Finally you will find the JBoss console output after a failed connection test:

```
12:03:55,221 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (HttpManagementService-threads - 7) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:356) [ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:304) [ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:834) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:379) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.internalTestConnection(AbstractPool.java:728) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool.testConnection(OnePool.java:89) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$TestConnectionInPool.invokeCommandOn(PoolOperations.java:143) [jboss-as-connector-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$1.execute(PoolOperations.java:82) [jboss-as-connector-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:702) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:537) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:338) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:314) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1144) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:331) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:201) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.processRequest(DomainApiHandler.java:295)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.doHandle(DomainApiHandler.java:179)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.handle(DomainApiHandler.java:186)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectAssociationHandler$1.run(SubjectAssociationHandler.java:69)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectAssociationHandler$1.run(SubjectAssociationHandler.java:65)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:94) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SubjectAssociationHandler.java:65)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectAssociationHandler.handle(SubjectAssociationHandler.java:59)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiCheckHandler.handle(DomainApiCheckHandler.java:45)
        at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:78)
        at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:81)
        at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:710)
        at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:78)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.RealmReadinessFilter.doFilter(RealmReadinessFilter.java:48)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DmrFailureReadinessFilter.doFilter(DmrFailureReadinessFilter.java:45)
        at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:81)
        at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:682)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2874)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2361)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:44)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2347)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:6276)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1794)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1405)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1069)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:905)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:452)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1014)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:328) [ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
        ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter from [Module "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc:main" from local module loader @65b57dcc (finder: local module finder @6e56103e (roots: D:\jboss-eap-6.4\modules,D:\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base))]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
        ... 50 more

12:09:24,991 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (HttpManagementService-threads - 9) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:356) [ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:304) [ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:834) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:379) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.internalTestConnection(AbstractPool.java:728) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool.testConnection(OnePool.java:89) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$TestConnectionInPool.invokeCommandOn(PoolOperations.java:143) [jboss-as-connector-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.common.pool.PoolOperations$1.execute(PoolOperations.java:82) [jboss-as-connector-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:702) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:537) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:338) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:314) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1144) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:331) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:201) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.processRequest(DomainApiHandler.java:295)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.doHandle(DomainApiHandler.java:179)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.handle(DomainApiHandler.java:186)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectAssociationHandler$1.run(SubjectAssociationHandler.java:69)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectAssociationHandler$1.run(SubjectAssociationHandler.java:65)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:94) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SubjectAssociationHandler.java:65)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectAssociationHandler.handle(SubjectAssociationHandler.java:59)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiCheckHandler.handle(DomainApiCheckHandler.java:45)
        at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:78)
        at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:81)
        at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:710)
        at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:78)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.RealmReadinessFilter.doFilter(RealmReadinessFilter.java:48)
        at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DmrFailureReadinessFilter.doFilter(DmrFailureReadinessFilter.java:45)
        at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:81)
        at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:682)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2874)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2361)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:44)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2347)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:6276)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1794)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1405)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1069)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:905)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:452)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1014)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:328) [ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.31.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.31.Final-redhat-1]
        ... 38 more
```

Comment: Similar to (technically duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39179398/creating-a-connection-with-wildfly-10-and-jaybird-3-0-fails

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I didn't search through Wildfly questions because I didn't know if there were any changes regarding this specific subsystem/configuration. If you think it should be marked as duplicate, feel free to do so. Thank you again for your solution.

Comment: Well, my hesitations to close as duplicate are more with the fact it is for a different JDBC driver, and the answer I wrote there mention certain specifics for that driver that are not valid here. And especially as I have a gold hammer to close as duplicate with a single vote, I'd rather leave that decision to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver has a dependency on java.xml.bind. If you want to use that with JBoss/Wildfly, you will need to explicitly depend on it.

You need to add a dependency on `javax.xml.bind.api` to the dependencies of your `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc` module:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="sqljdbc.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/> <!-- Add this -->
    </dependencies>

</module>
```

Alternatively, consider upgrading the version of your Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver; recent versions of the driver don't need this dependency (based on the comments of the OP, version 6.4.0 works fine, higher versions are likely to work as well).

Comment: @noise An alternative solution might be to try and upgrade your JDBC driver, it looks like recent versions of the SQL Server JDBC driver no longer have this dependency (although I didn't check that exhaustively).

Comment: if the newer versions of the driver are compliant with Java 7 (which is a mandatory feature I cannot change, even though I know it's deprecated) I'll try for sure

Comment: The latest version of the driver for Java 7 is 6.4.0; I'm not sure if that version still has the dependency or not.

Comment: I just tried with the driver version you mentioned earlier (6.4.0). I can confirm that it works even without the last dependency `<module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>`. Thank you for your time

Comment: @noise Thanks, I have added a note about that in my answer.